# Extracting date from text in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, extract, array-formulas

One cell contains the text below:

Immediate_TAA_BRC 02/01/2021 12:30 PM-02/01/2021 9:00 PM

How do I extract only the first date: 02/01/2021

I have tried with SPLIT(RIGHT  functions but it returns some weird year in 19th century...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `REGEXEXTRACT` function here:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}")
```

Here the `A1` is a cell reference which might contain the text you gave as an example:

```
Immediate_TAA_BRC 02/01/2021 12:30 PM-02/01/2021 9:00 PM
```

Note that `REGEXEXTRACT` by default returns the first matching portion of text, which works well in this case because you want to match the first date.

Comment: Great thanks, that worked to some extent, I have used this formula inside "if" as the formula being dragged down does not always look into text cell, sometimes looks into cell which reads "off" or is blank. Can this formula be updated to take this into account. My current formula reads:                                                                   
 =if(H3="","",if(H3="off","off",(REGEXEXTRACT(H3,"02/......."))))

Comment: I can't answer this comment without seeing your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+/\d+/\d+")
```

or arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+/\d+/\d+")))
```

---

update:

use in row 3

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H3:H="",,IF(H3:H="off", "off", 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(H3:H, "\d+/\d+/\d+")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to extract the date, there are two options:

1. Using [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en). With the formula that player0 has provided, you take the numbers that are between the first two `/`:

   ```
   =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+/\d+/\d+")
   ```
2. Using [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625), [MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) and [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)

   - Use `FIND` to get the positions of the first two blank spaces:

     - `B1 = FIND(" ", A1)` - position of first blank space
     - `B2 = FIND(" ", A1, B1+1)` - the last parameter indicates the character where the search starts
     - `RESULT = TRIM(MID(A1, B1, B2-B1))` - how the formula looks like with intermediate calculations. With `MID` you take `B2-B1` characters from a string starting on the `B1` position. `TRIM` just emoves leading, trailing spaces.
     - ```
       FINAL RESULT = TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
       ```

### How to deal with more cells with different value types

1. Using [SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en)

   - First argument: cell with the text
   - Second and third: condition and value if `TRUE`
   - Four and five: second condition if needed, you can use multiple conditions
   - Last one: default value

   ```
   =SWITCH(A1, "", "BLANK CELL", "OFF", "OFF CELL", 
   REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+/\d+/\d+"))
   ```

   or

   ```
   =SWITCH(A1, "", "BLANK CELL", "OFF", "OFF CELL", 
   TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1))))
   ```